# Suspend explorer.exe rather than killing the process

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Because my favorite game StarCraft looks rather ugly (colors are broken) on new versions on windows, I use a batch file to kill explorer and make the game look normal:

```
rem Kill the explorer process
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
rem If an application is run directly, the batch will wait for the process to end
Starcraft.exe
rem start commands starts process in diferent thread, so that this window can close
start explorer.exe
```

I do this because use of the compatibility mode reduced the issue but did not remove it completely.

However, it bothers me that all my open windows of explorer will not be re-opened when the process is started again.
Can the explorer be just suspended or gracefully closed so that the open explorer windows will remain?

What I'm doing might also be useful for people who need to free some RAM before starting a game.

Comment: Can be explorer be suspended gracefully; no it cannot

Comment: Ramhound is correct. You cannot achieve what you want by suspending explorer.exe. Firslty, suspending the process will just freeze it in its current state (still visible). Secondly, if you kill explorer, than you kill all processes running under it. Could you explain why are you doing it at all? What do you mean by "StarCraft looks rather ugly"

Comment: Rather then killing Windows Explorer you probably should [open the Compatibility dialog](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html) and enable either **Disable desktop composition**, **Disable visual themes**, or both.

Comment: Have you tried this @and31415? I have spend a lots of time to get the StarCraft to render properly and none of the compatibility solutions have worked.
It seems that windows explorer is rendering something even when it's in background, and that makes it necessary to turn it off to avoid [crippled colors in the game](http://deroitcityg.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/starcraft-color-fix.jpg?w=640&h=480).

Comment: Have you tried this fix for the color problem? It doesn't involve killing explorer.exe and works for other games that have similar issues. http://aok.heavengames.com/blacksmith/showfile.php?fileid=11108

Comment: @TomášZato I don't have Starcraft installed, but you didn't specify whether you tried the compatibility options already, so I thought it was worth suggesting it. Anyway, Blizzard did have a specific article with a fix but it looks like the link is dead now. Here's a forum where they provide the official fix: [StarCraft Brood War Windows 7 Color Fix (registry)](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/brood-war/374126-starcraft-brood-war-windows-7-color-fix-registry). Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are covered. Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8210/

Comment: Thanks for the link, however I've already found different solution. I'd like to point out though, that I'm not asking how to fix broken colors in starcraft in my question. I just failed to abstract the problem enough. Also, I believe you missed a line in the question: *I do this because use of the compatibility mode reduced the issue but did not remove it completely.* [Here's the solution I've used](http://aok.heavengames.com/blacksmith/showfile.php?fileid=11108) (and works).

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. once you killed the process explorer.exe you can't retrieve every thing managed bye the explorer (windows-clipboards-...)
The best to do is to use Windows Classic Theme and shutdown all processes that you don't need while playing e.g. download managers